# Why does NPM install require sudo to install everything?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a weird issue in my repo, that did work yesterday. When I run `npm install` it goes on without any issues, but the problem is that not all packages was installed. There are multiple modules that is missing in under `node_modules/@types` that I have defined in my packages.json.

I also miss some of the files that should be added to `node_modules/bin`, like nodemon. It does work if I run `sudo npm install` but that doesn't feel right.

I did update my npm and node version to latest lts, npm 6.14.15 and node 14.17.6.

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Blah blah blah",
  "author": "Tomas Jansson",
  "main": "./bin/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/arm-containerservice": "^13.3.0",
    "@azure/arm-subscriptions": "^3.1.0",
    "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth": "^3.0.10",
    "@azure/msal-node": "^1.2.0",
    "@kubernetes/client-node": "^0.15.0",
    "@pulumi/azure-native": "^1.16.0",
    "@pulumi/azuread": "^4.3.0",
    "@pulumi/github": "^4.2.0",
    "@pulumi/kubernetes": "^3.5.1",
    "@pulumi/pulumi": "^3.7.0",
    "@pulumi/random": "^4.2.0",
    "@pulumi/tls": "^4.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-azure-ad": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.2",
    "@types/passport-azure-ad": "^4.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node ./bin/index.js",
    "watch": "nodemon ./index.ts"
  }
}
```

Any ideas why I need to use sudo?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your user permissions for `node_modules` folder in your project are mismatched.

One possible way to fix this would be to remove the `node_modules` (using sudo) and then run `npm install` again.  You should also verify your user is the owner of the project folder and the permissions from `ls -l` show you are allowed to read+write.

A common reason this can happen if you're using Docker is that the user in the Docker container is likely root and the volume is being mapped between your host and container.  You can change COPY commands to include a user:group such as `COPY --chown=$USER_ID:$GROUP_ID app` and pass these as build args to docker `docker-compose build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u) --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g)`

Comment: I did try removing the modules folder and also lock file before posting the question with no luck. I’ve also checked that it is me and not root that is the owner of current folder.

Comment: There's nothing in this package.json that would cause this, and locally for me it installs everything fine.  Are you on a Mac?  Do you, perhaps, have some backup tool that's trying to restore things and giving it the wrong permissions?

Answer (score -2):

so it deepness if the module is like (ffmpeg, nodemon or others) that are scripts that don't normally go in the runtime then you would need to use sudo but not all the time like using axios you would not need to use sudo to install, but if in doubt sudo it out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).